# how to solve the differential equation $\sin^{2}(dy/dx)- x = 0$ for $y(0)=0$ and what is its domain for this point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

how to solve the differential equation $\sin^{2}(dy/dx) - x = 0$ for $y(0) = 0$ and what is its domain for this point?

Note: I have calculated it with online tools, so i am not asking the result. I am asking the steps for the result.

Note2: The question is true, it is exactly as i wrote it.( It is not like sin^2(x) etc.) No editing required.

Comment: What "solution" did the online tools give you?  Is ask because no solution has a point on the $y$-axis.

Comment: This is not really an ODE, it is just an integration/quadrature problem with singular integrals. Can you check that the equation is complete as it is written here? There could possibly be a factor $y(x)$ missing in the second term.

Comment: the question is true, no edit required

Comment: Do you mean $\sin^2(x) y'$ or $\sin^2(y')$? The latter is an extremely weird thing to write, since $\sin^2$ is extremely non-injective...

Comment: No, the question is exactly as i wrote. I could not do it because dy/dx was inside the sin function

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense, what's the privileged choice of the inverse of $\sin^2$? Maybe the one with range $[0,\pi/2]$?

Answer (score 0):

By the non-negativity of the square, your equation is defined on $x\in [0,1]$ and can be simplified to $\cos(2y'(x))=1-2x$. Then with the inverse cosine
$$
y'(x)=k\pi\pm\frac12\arccos(1-2x).
$$
Each $k\in\Bbb Z$ gives a valid solution.